# Use of Jokers in Poker

Tags: poker-texas-holdem, poker

What versions of poker allow Jokers to be included in the deck?
Are they treated as wildcards / how are they scored?

To date I've only played with a 52 card deck (i.e. where jokers would only be used to replace a specific lost card to make up an incomplete deck).

Comment: Use of a joker in poker is not common.  It messes with the order of hands.  Two pair is now less common than trips.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll find jokers used in live poker (against other humans) in a casino. However, there are **many** variations of poker played in home games that use jokers and/or other wild cards. In home games, the rules are quite varied because usually the person suggesting the game (dealer's choice) gets to make whatever rules they'd like. Typically though, the Joker is treated as a wild card which you can assign any value you wish. Scoring (hand ranking) is done identically to without wild cards, except that now 5 of a kind is possible, and that is the best hand. (5 deuces beats a royal flush, and 5 Aces is the best possible hand.)

This page lists some [home poker games that use jokers.](http://www.homepokeredge.com/gpage11.html)

Comment: If wild cards are allowed in a game, they lose to "tie" hands; a "natural" hand beats one using wildcards. So a hand with 3 "real" aces beats one ace and two jokers pretending they are aces.

Comment: @MarkRipley - another way to word that is when hands are tied, the hand with the fewest wild cards wins (or if they have the same number of wildcards it remains a tie).

Comment: Twos and one eyed jacks :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a version of texas hold em' we play with jokers. They add some spice and diversity to the game. These are the rules we play by. Jokers are worth nothing on their own but they are allowed to complete straights and flushes. Jokers may NOT be used with regular cards to create pairs, trips, four of a kind, or a full house, however, when both jokers are in play, whether in your hand or as a community card, they can be used together to make a pair that ranks one higher than an ace pair. A joker pair may be used in conjunction with three of a kind to make a full house, i.e. three kings and two jokers. Often when both jokers are out in play, the 'high pair' rule doesn't come into effect because both jokers can be used together on the same straight or flush making higher hands much easier to come by.